# Flutter - Screen orientation when orientation is locked

Tags: flutter, camera, orientation

I'm creating a camera screen for my Flutter app. I need to know if the user is holding the phone upright(portrait) or sideways(landscape).

1. I have fixed the orientation of the screen to portraitUp.
2. I have tried using the OrientationBuilder widget, but it does not work if the orientation is fixed.
3. Another approach would be to get the screen width and height as the user captures the image, and see which value is larger to decide the orientation. But MediaQuery.of(context).size is also not changing if the orientation is fixed.

Is there any other way I can get to know if the user is holding the phone upright(portrait) or sideways(landscape) after locking the orientation to portraitUp??

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So, with some more digging I could find the orientation using the [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) package!

Given below is the code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sensors_plus/sensors_plus.dart';

class OrientationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrientationWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<OrientationWidget> createState() => _OrientationWidgetState();
}

class _OrientationWidgetState extends State<OrientationWidget> {
  double? x, y, z;

  String orientation = 'Portrait';

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent e) {
        x = e.x;
        y = e.y;
        z = e.z;
        setState(() {});
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (x != null && y != null) {
      if(x! > -1.5 && x! < 1.5 && y! > 8) {
        orientation = 'Portrait';
      } else if (x! > 8.5 && y! > -1.5 && y! < 1.5) {
        orientation = 'Landscape Left';
      } else if (x! < -8.5 && y! > -1.5 && y! < 1.5) {
        orientation = 'Landscape Right';
      }
    }

    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Orientation : $orientation',
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But still not able to figure if the landscape orientation is landscapeLeft or landscapeRight. If anyone is able to fing that solution, please do post!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the direction using this plugin : [flutter_sensors](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sensors)

and this code:

```
StreamSubscription sensorSubscription;

sensorSubscription = userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
  if (event.x > 0.5) {
    print("Rotated to LandscapeRight");
  } else if (event.x < -0.5) {
    print("Rotated to LandscapeLeft");
  } else if (event.y > 0.5) {
    print("Rotated to PortraitUp");
  } else if (event.y < -0.5) {
    print("Rotated to PortraitDown");
  }
});
```

Comment: These values are not accurate.